# When using rsync, need a particular file to be transferred prior to another

Tags: rsync

From rsync manpage

> **SORTED TRANSFER ORDER**
>
> Rsync always sorts the specified filenames into its internal transfer
>   list. This handles the merging together of the contents of identically
>   named directories, makes it easy to remove duplicate filenames, and
>   may confuse someone when the files are transferred in a different
>   order than what was given on the command-line.
>
> If you need a particular file to be transferred prior to another,
>   either separate the files into different rsync calls, or **consider
>   using --delay-updates (which doesn't affect the sorted transfer order,
>   but does make the final file-updating phase happen much more
>   rapidly)**.

Since --delay-updates doesn't affect the sorted transfer order, how can it help  if we "need a particular file to be transferred prior to another"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> how can it help if we "need a particular file to be transferred prior
>   to another"?

Under normal circumstances, files are copied one at a time.  So if the order is incorrect, then the "wrong" file can be updated ahead of the other for quite some time.

With --delay-updates, the files are copied over a period of time, but then placed correctly into the filesystem very quickly at the end.  The files may be copied out of order, but window of time when someone on the destination might be able to tell that is much smaller than normal.

It doesn't fix the order, but it does make the race condition less likely to lose.

Comment: Thanks .How does race condition happen and matter here,?

Comment: Imagine you want to transfer "B", "A", but rsync sorts it as "A", "B".  Then after file "A" is placed, the race is between your application noticing "A" is in place without "B" versus rsync getting file "B" in place.